# Pseudo class for just appended div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that i am using to append some text. This is the html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="append"></div>
    <div class="roulette">
    </div>
    <button class="spinner"></button>  
</div>
```

This is the jquery

```
var clickHandler = function() {
  $('.spinner').off('click');
  $('.spinner span').hide();
  $r.spin().done(function(price) {
   //$('.append').text('You won: ' + price.name);
    $('.append').text('Points: ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 100 );
    $('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
    $('.spinner span').show();
    $('.spinner').css({"border": "none"});
  });
};

$('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
```

This is the css that hides the divs border

```
.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("img/small_circle.png") no-repeat 30% 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border:none !important;
  top: -40px !important;
  left: 57px;
  bottom:100px !important;
  z-index:1000 !important;
}
```

When i append some text to the div append, the div spinner shows an orange border line that i did not ask for my code. How should i target the just appended div now that i want to hide the active border?.

`.spinner:focus{}` does not seem to work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6QUx.png)

Comment: What is `$r`? And what is `.spin()`. Please post all the relevant code. Maybe you should try `outline: none;` in your CSS. Make a runnable snippet that shows the problem you say you have

Comment: This line is the only one doing the appendg `    `$('.append').text('Points: ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 100 );`

Comment: Did you try css style "outline: none;" ?

Comment: @hallleron that has worked.

Comment: [Don't use "outline: none"](http://www.outlinenone.com/)